# Assigning new column based on frequency of items in a groupby & normalized date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains dates & times of employees swiping in to work. I am looking to take the swipes data, bucket it into different shifts, then figure out which shift the employee swiped the most times in that particular day & return that as a new column in an effort to normalize the shift. You'll see below employees have multiple swipes across all three shifts, but I want to assign a new column with the shift number for whichever shift has the most swipes for that particular employee on that particular day.

Here is the hypothetical df:

```
np.random.seed(1111)
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'Employee':np.random.choice( ['E-1','E-2','E-3'], 500),
    'Date':pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=500, freq='.5H'),
    'Hours': np.random.randint(0,23,size=500),
    'Minutes':np.random.randint(0,59,500)
     })

df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + " " + df.Hours.astype(str) +":"+ df.Minutes.astype(str))

df['time'] = df['date_time'].dt.strftime("%H:%M")
```

I then bucket the data into shifts using this method. Please note that an employee's shift may start at 7am (07:00), but they often clock in before shift starts, so the conditions below are slightly different than the stated employee shifts (First Shift = 7am-3:30pm, Second Shift 3:00pm-11pm, Third Shift= 11pm-7am).

```
conditions = [
    ((df['time'].le('06:53')) | df['time'].ge('22:53')),
    (df['time'].ge('06:53') & df['time'].lt('15:23')),
    (df['time'].ge('15:23') & df['time'].le('22:52'))
]

choices = ['Third','First','Second']
df['shift'] = np.select(conditions, choices,default='NA')
```

I would like to group to see the number of swipes per date, employee, & shift to then assign a new column for each row that shows which shift had the most action for that specific employee on that specific date. The new column (call it master_shift) would contain First, Second, or Third - whichever shift had the most swipes for that employee & date.

For instance - if I perform a groupby to get the number of swipes per date, employee, & shift like so:

```
df.groupby([df['Date'].dt.date,'Employee','shift'])\
    .agg({'date_time':'nunique'})\
    .rename(columns={'date_time':'swipes'})
```

I would expect that Date 2011-01-01 and Employee E-1, the new column would say 'Third' for master_shift as E-1 had 5 swipes for First shift, four for Second shift, & 8 for Third shift. In this hypothetical data set,

I am sure there's some version of transform and idxmax I'm missing, but I can't seem to get there.

As a bonus question, I would love to create a 'normalized_date', as the company I'm creating the analysis for would have recognize a work day as 7am-7am, not midnight to midnight. Any hours after midnight before 7am should be the prior day under 'normalized_date' column.

Thank you in advance for any help you can offer!

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? What part are you struggling with?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this

```
# groupby and nunique
new = df.groupby([df['Date'].dt.date,'Employee','shift'])['date_time'].nunique()

# filter the new dataframe using groupby to keep the max value
new.loc[new.groupby(level=[0,1]).idxmax()].to_frame()

                            date_time
Date       Employee shift            
2011-01-01 E-1      Third           8
           E-2      Second          6
           E-3      First           5
2011-01-02 E-1      First           6
           E-2      First           9
           E-3      Third           8
2011-01-03 E-1      Third           8
           E-2      First           8
           E-3      First           9
2011-01-04 E-1      First           6
           E-2      First           8
           E-3      Third           9
2011-01-05 E-1      Third           7
           E-2      First           9
           E-3      First           4
2011-01-06 E-1      First           6
           E-2      First           8
           E-3      Second         10
2011-01-07 E-1      First           7
           E-2      First           8
           E-3      Second         10
2011-01-08 E-1      First           9
           E-2      First           7
           E-3      First           6
2011-01-09 E-1      Second          5
           E-2      Third           8
           E-3      Second          6
2011-01-10 E-1      First           6
           E-2      First          12
           E-3      First           4
2011-01-11 E-1      First           7
           E-2      First           2
           E-3      Second          2
```

## Update

```
# groupby and use pd.Grouper to groupby a 7-7 workday and the get nunique
new = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='24h', base=7), 'Employee','shift'])['date_time'].nunique()
# groupby and get the max
df2 = new.loc[new.groupby(level=[0,1]).idxmax()].to_frame().reset_index()
# format and rename columns
df2 = df2[df2.columns[:3]]
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])
df2 = df2.rename(columns={'shift': 'master_shift'})
# merge on date and employee
final = df.merge(df2, left_on=[df['Date'].dt.date, 'Employee'], right_on=[df2['Date'].dt.date, 'Employee'])
```

I should note that this groups the dates together starting at 7am on one day to 6:59am the next day and not midnight to 11:59 on the same day.

Comment: thank you for your quick response. That is close, however I'm looking to assign a new column to the original dataframe that shows a master_shift with the assignment being whichever shift for that particular date & employee had the most hits. It's the only way I can think of to assign a shift that accounts for someone swiping in originally at 06:35 (which would show 3rd shift) but really working 1st shift which you'd see they'd have many more swipes between 7am & 3:30pm. Thanks!

Comment: @keg5038 check out the update. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: it's getting closer, but it's creating new columns like 'key_0', 'Date_x', 'Date_y' that are not there to begin with.

Comment: @keg5038 you can just drop those extra columns. If this is not what you are looking for please provide a sample expected output.